# AdMob Response message is null or zero length

Tags: android, admob

So, I've been trying to implement AdMob API's in my app for several days and I've basically copied and pasted the basic sample code provided. It seems to be working, but I keep getting `onFailedToReceiveAd(A network error occurred).` and `Response is null or zero length.`

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="ragingsoftware.android.AdsTest"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"/>

</application>
</manifest>
```

Here is my main layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutMain">
<TextView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/hello"
/>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my Activity code:

```
private void initAds() {
    // Create the adView
    AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it’s been given
    // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearLayoutMain);
    // Add the adView to it
    layout.addView(adView);
    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
}
```

And last, but not least, the logcat:

```
03-20 00:48:37.569: INFO/Ads(12511): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://www.gstatic.com/afma/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_buildAdURL({"msid":"ragingsoftware.android.WiFiScheduler","hl":"en","preqs":0,"u_so":"p","slotname":"a14d83d19c4eaef","js":"afma-sdk-a-v4.0.2","app_name":"4.0.2.android.ragingsoftware.android.WiFiScheduler","isu":"358ABB21689377B8D76F4A16B987E097","u_audio":1,"u_w":320,"format":"320x50_mb","u_sd":1.0,"net":"ed","u_h":480});</script></head><body></body></html>
03-20 00:48:39.059: INFO/Ads(12511): Received ad url: <"url": "http://r.admob.com:80/ad_source.php?msid=ragingsoftware.android.WiFiScheduler&hl=en&preqs=0&u_so=p&slotname=a14d83d19c4eaef&js=afma-sdk-a-v4.0.2&app_name=4.0.2.android.ragingsoftware.android.WiFiScheduler&isu=358ABB21689377B8D76F4A16B987E097&u_audio=1&u_w=320&format=320x50_mb&u_sd=1&net=ed&u_h=480&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=240&ex=1&client_sdk=1", "afmaNotifyDt": "null">
03-20 00:48:42.599: INFO/Ads(12511): AdLoader timed out while getting the HTML.
03-20 00:48:42.599: INFO/Ads(12511): onFailedToReceiveAd(A network error occurred.)
03-20 00:48:42.619: INFO/Ads(12511): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://www.gstatic.com/afma/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_buildAdURL({"msid":"ragingsoftware.android.WiFiScheduler","hl":"en","preqs":1,"u_so":"p","slotname":"a14d83d19c4eaef","js":"afma-sdk-a-v4.0.2","app_name":"4.0.2.android.ragingsoftware.android.WiFiScheduler","isu":"358ABB21689377B8D76F4A16B987E097","u_audio":1,"u_w":320,"format":"320x50_mb","u_sd":1.0,"net":"ed","u_h":480});</script></head><body></body></html>
03-20 00:48:43.179: INFO/Ads(12511): Received ad url: <"url": "http://r.admob.com:80/ad_source.php?msid=ragingsoftware.android.WiFiScheduler&hl=en&preqs=1&u_so=p&slotname=a14d83d19c4eaef&js=afma-sdk-a-v4.0.2&app_name=4.0.2.android.ragingsoftware.android.WiFiScheduler&isu=358ABB21689377B8D76F4A16B987E097&u_audio=1&u_w=320&format=320x50_mb&u_sd=1&net=ed&u_h=480&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=240&ex=1&client_sdk=1&askip=1", "afmaNotifyDt": "null">
03-20 00:48:47.630: INFO/Ads(12511): AdLoader timed out while getting the HTML.
03-20 00:48:47.649: INFO/Ads(12511): onFailedToReceiveAd(A network error occurred.)
03-20 00:48:47.869: INFO/Ads(12511): Response message is null or zero length: 
03-20 00:48:48.119: INFO/Ads(12511): Response message is null or zero length: 
03-20 00:50:00.219: INFO/Ads(12511): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://www.gstatic.com/afma/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_buildAdURL({"msid":"ragingsoftware.android.WiFiScheduler","hl":"en","preqs":2,"u_so":"p","slotname":"a14d83d19c4eaef","js":"afma-sdk-a-v4.0.2","app_name":"4.0.2.android.ragingsoftware.android.WiFiScheduler","isu":"358ABB21689377B8D76F4A16B987E097","u_audio":1,"u_w":320,"format":"320x50_mb","u_sd":1.0,"net":"ed","u_h":480});</script></head><body></body></html>
03-20 00:50:00.219: INFO/Ads(12511): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://www.gstatic.com/afma/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_buildAdURL({"msid":"ragingsoftware.android.WiFiScheduler","hl":"en","preqs":2,"u_so":"p","slotname":"a14d83d19c4eaef","js":"afma-sdk-a-v4.0.2","app_name":"4.0.2.android.ragingsoftware.android.WiFiScheduler","isu":"358ABB21689377B8D76F4A16B987E097","u_audio":1,"u_w":320,"format":"320x50_mb","u_sd":1.0,"net":"ed","u_h":480});</script></head><body></body></html>
03-20 00:50:00.909: INFO/Ads(12511): Received ad url: <"url": "http://r.admob.com:80/ad_source.php?msid=ragingsoftware.android.WiFiScheduler&hl=en&preqs=2&u_so=p&slotname=a14d83d19c4eaef&js=afma-sdk-a-v4.0.2&app_name=4.0.2.android.ragingsoftware.android.WiFiScheduler&isu=358ABB21689377B8D76F4A16B987E097&u_audio=1&u_w=320&format=320x50_mb&u_sd=1&net=ed&u_h=480&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=240&ex=1&client_sdk=1&askip=2", "afmaNotifyDt": "null">
03-20 00:50:00.909: INFO/Ads(12511): Received ad url: <"url": "http://r.admob.com:80/ad_source.php?msid=ragingsoftware.android.WiFiScheduler&hl=en&preqs=2&u_so=p&slotname=a14d83d19c4eaef&js=afma-sdk-a-v4.0.2&app_name=4.0.2.android.ragingsoftware.android.WiFiScheduler&isu=358ABB21689377B8D76F4A16B987E097&u_audio=1&u_w=320&format=320x50_mb&u_sd=1&net=ed&u_h=480&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=240&ex=1&client_sdk=1&askip=2", "afmaNotifyDt": "null">
03-20 00:50:05.248: INFO/Ads(12511): AdLoader timed out while getting the HTML.
03-20 00:50:05.249: INFO/Ads(12511): onFailedToReceiveAd(A network error occurred.)
03-20 00:50:05.248: INFO/Ads(12511): AdLoader timed out while getting the HTML.
03-20 00:50:05.249: INFO/Ads(12511): onFailedToReceiveAd(A network error occurred.)
03-20 00:50:05.509: INFO/Ads(12511): Response message is null or zero length:
```

I've been googling for days now and can't find an answer. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Perhaps you are blocking ads?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the test mode to true to show the Test Ad on emulator.

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, " a14e01a2c440ee1");
layout.addView(adView);
AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
**request.setTesting(true);**    
adView.loadAd(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, it seems to me that you are missing in the manifest the application's publisher ID assigned by AdMob. You need to add a meta-data field like this:

`<meta-data android:value="ADMOB_ID" android:name="ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID" />`

Where `ADMOB_ID` is the ID assigned by AdMob.

Comment: I'm using the older SDK which is different, but I assumed "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" was his ID.

Comment: I added the <meta-data/> as you suggested and I'm still seeing the error messages described my my original post. I'm also seeing these:

`AdLoader timed out while getting the HTML`

And

`Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required`

Comment: You can ignore buffer size related message - the reason is definetely in some other area.

Comment: OK, just for grins and giggles, I copied several of the ad URL's into my browser and the response actually **is** empty. Maybe this is an issue on the AdMob side of things? I vaguely remember reading somewhere that AdMob isn't fully serving ads or something like that. I don't know, but it's frustrating because I need to implement ads for a client project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same error for Android < 2.0, but it works for Android > 2.0. I'm currently testing on the emulator. Admob SDK is supposed to be compatible for Android 1.5, but it looks like it doesn't!

Answer (score 0):

I m new in android, my answer may not help to you but as per my knowledge admob sdk send add request after few time interval so u can try with adwhirl

https://www.adwhirl.com/doc/android/AdWhirlAndroidSDKSetup.html

The AdWhirl for Android SDK maximizes your app’s advertising revenue via trivial integration of up to four mobile ad networks:

1) AdMob
2) Google AdSense for Mobile Applications
3) Millennial Media
4) ZestADZ